# Visual Studio - forcing a project to use an earlier version of Boost?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost

For now, I just want to get a clean compile. Will document the issues and rebuild Boost later.

I have vc90 installed of Boost, but Visual Studio is looking for vc100:

`error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib'`

I have installed:

`libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_47.lib`

Is there somewhere I can change it so it uses vc90?

Comment: checked the toolset settings in your project file?

Comment: Calling it "Visual C" and talking about a C++ library like Boost is an enormous Red Flag.  So is "rebuild Boost later".  You're kinda lost here, impossible to unravel the "hope it works but it didn't" post.

Comment: @HansPassant - sorry brain fart on my side, meant Visual Studio, have revised the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - c++ libraries are not compatible - one compiler (one version) and a matching library.

In your case install boost libraries for vc100 or downgrade to vc90.